# Ubuntu 18.04 no Cups admin login page

Tags: printing

Ubuntu 18.04 (both 32 bit and 64 bit) has no Cups login page.
The page that comes up from http://localhost:631/admin has no login site. This is first time it has occurred

Comment: Are you using Chrome?  This is a known bug now:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cups/+bug/1769893  It does work fine with Firefox.  I have not tried any other browsers yet.

Comment: Is `cupsd` running (`pgrep cupsd`, `service cups status`)?

Comment: Firefox runs same as Chrome=no luck there either

Comment: Cups running?699 is response

Comment: http://localhost:631/admin/login will take you to the page.  However, in Chrome it will not stay as a log in and you will get unauthorized on pages.

Comment: Thank you     Firefox does work   First time I didn't click on an item for the login to come up.   Ubuntu forums never responded to this question.  Guess you just have to Ask Ubuntu

Comment: The admin/login page redirects back to the normal page without any way to login on both Firefox & Chromium